# Android - wrong values from NativeHead via Debug class?

Tags: java, android, memory, heap-memory

I tried to get some info from **Debug** class in my **OnCreate** method by using:

```
getNativeHeapAllocatedSize() - Returns the amount of allocated memory in the native heap.
getNativeHeapFreeSize() - Returns the amount of free memory in the native heap.
getNativeHeapSize() - Returns the size of the native heap.
```

And this is what i get:

```
HeapSize: 4.2mb 
UsedHeapSize: 4.19mb
RemainingHeapSize: 0.05mb
```

But how? i have just 4.2 mb nHeap for my app and used 99% of it?
Just in **OnCreate** method?

Can somebody explain why?

*(Testing on Android 2.3)*

Thanks.